# How to launch instance with more storage in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm running instances in AWS using following:

```
input := &ec2.RunInstancesInput{
    // .... assign parameters
}
reservation, err := ec2session.RunInstancesWithContext(ctx, input)
```

I'd like to supply storage size of the storage volume, just as it can be specified in the AWS Console in the 'Add Storage' tab.

However, I can't configure RunInstancesInput for initial storage size, so it launches with whatever default size for the instance type.

I can attach another volume later, but I want to specify initial volume size.

Is it possible, and how to do it?

Comment: Try including a block device mapping for the root volume (/dev/sda1) that indicates a larger size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it was already suggested in comments, you should add `BlockDeviceMapping` into your request. Here is an example of how to do it in Java.

```
private static BlockDeviceMapping blockDeviceMapping(int systemDiskSizeInGb)
{
    EbsBlockDevice ebs = new EbsBlockDevice()
            .withVolumeSize(systemDiskSizeInGb)
            .withVolumeType(VolumeType.Gp2);
    return new BlockDeviceMapping()
            .withDeviceName("/dev/sda1")
            .withEbs(ebs);
}

private static RunInstancesRequest buildInstanceRequest(String imageId, int systemDiskSizeInGb)
{
    return new RunInstancesRequest()
            .withImageId(imageId)
            .withBlockDeviceMappings(ImmutableSet.of(blockDeviceMapping(systemDiskSizeInGb)));
}

RunInstancesResult result = this.ec2Client.runInstances(request);
```